# Auto install setup in virtual machine

Tags: unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration, virtual-machine, continuous-deployment

I have a build system, it makes me the build of my c# software, and then runs a build to make my setup and deploys it into a repository.

Now, what I need is, after this deployment, I need this setup installed on a virtual machine or sandbox.

How can I do that? Is there any software that does this for me?

For example, after the build of setup is done, this software with my own configuration, takes my setup and install in silent mode in this VM/ sandbox, and then if I want I can run also tests.

**The main idea is, whenever a build is deployed, it's automatically installed in a machine** for me, to quickly see the result/ run tests, otherwise I need always, after build, open machine, install and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into the use of [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for such a setup.
Once you finish the build and have the installer ready, you can mount/copy it into a new VM you provision with Vagrant.
You then add the installation command to your **Vagrantfile** (file describing your VM configuration and setup).

This is a very common setup for automated build, install and test scenarios.

I hope this helps.